# How to change syntax "inputs" property to "@Input" property decorator

Tags: typescript, angular, tslint

I have a piece of code which look like this

```
@Component({
    selector: 'control-messages',
    inputs: ['controlName: control'],
    template: `<div *ngIf="errorMessage !== null">{{errorMessage}}</div>`
})
```

How do I change it to @Input() property decorator.

Answer (score 2):

Should be like:

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'control-messages',
    template: `<div *ngIf="errorMessage !== null">{{errorMessage}}</div>`
})

export class YourClass{
    @Input()
    controlName: control;

    constructor() {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

Comment: it might be helpful to include a link to the documentation, just so people know it exists. :) https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Input-var.html

Comment: For the example given -- `inputs: ['controlName: control']` -- `control` is not a type, it is an alias.  See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 2):

See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#inputs-outputs

```
inputs:['controlName: control']  // propertyName: alias

@Input('control') controlName: optional_type;  //  @Input('alias') propertyName:type
```

So if `controlName` is a string:

```
@Input('control') controlName: string;
```